# mod rewrite redirect

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

All,

I am very new to mod rewrite. I need to redirect any user with "citzenhawk" parameter in their url to my url

For example:

`http://www.mywebsite.com/?sc=CX12N003&cm_mmc=affiliate-_-citizenhawk-_-nooffer-_-na&prfc=5&clickid=0004c845fa9a87050a4277221a003262`

Should result in a redirect to:

`http://www.mywebsite.com/`

Here are my rewrite conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (&|^)cm_mmc=(.*)citizenhawk(.*)(&|$)$
RewriteRule ^/rrs/ [NC,R=302,L]
```

Where am i going wrong? Can someone help me with example please.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cm_mmc=[^&]*citizenhawk [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &cm_mmc=[^&]*citizenhawk
RewriteRule .* / [R=permanent,L]
```

This will redirect any request which contains "citizenhawk" within a query-string variable called cm_mmc. It issues a permanent (code 301) request, but leave it as `R=302` if this is only a temporary redirect.

It's not clear why you were checking for requests for `/rrs/` so I've used `.*` to capture all requests.

Comment: Thanks user1515834 for your response. I do not have any testing environment and do not wish to put this in production without testing. Is there any online tool available so i can test this condition? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: None of which I know. If you're running a production environment you really need to be running a test rig configured as closely to the production rig as possible, so that you can see how changes will take effect. Failing that, maybe change the variable name and keyword to a couple of test values (such as test_mmc and citizentest) and then see if those test values redirect as needed. Then change to the real values once you're confident the redirect works.